# How to get source path and alternate text values from properties file in Struts2 for inserting images? In Struts1 altKey and srcKey were used for this

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts, ognl

I would like to know what the replacement is for the `altKey` and `srcKey` attributes in the `<html:img>` tag in Struts 2.

What I want to achieve is to be able to **insert an image with source path from properties file**. Similar to what `srcKey` does in Struts1.

And even for the altertnate text, I want to know how to get that from the properties file like the `altKey` in Struts1.

```xml
<s:url var="url" value="/image/test.jpg"/>
<img src="${url}" border="0" alt="Test">
```

This works but the source for image is directly mentioned here. I would want to get that value from the properties file.

I want to migrate the below code to Struts 2. How do I do this?

```xml
<html:img width="10" height="10" align="middle" altKey="alt.logo" srcKey="image.logo" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your action class should extend `ActionSupport`. Then you can use something like

```xml
<s:url var="url" value="%{getText('image.logo')}"/>
<img src="${url}" border="0" alt="<s:text name='alt.logo'/>">
```